# Can PMD check file existence?

Tags: xml, file, pmd

Is it possible to check file existence via PMD?

To be more specific, I have xml with something like this:

```
<node filename="path/file">
```

I want to warn developers that this file could be missing. Is it really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible if you write a [Java rule](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/howtowritearule.html).  I don't know if it is possible with a XPath rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But personally, I prefer XPAth rules, it would be a better solution, in my opinion.

Comment: Understood.  The XPath rules are less powerful though.  I've encountered a few things that can be done in Java but not XPath.  In fact, that's been our rule of thumb.  Use XPath for custom rules when possible.